# Using OR Operator For Null Values in IIF Statement

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, null, iif

I've got a MS access form with optional criteria for running a query. The user will select a checkbox and enter a value then run the query based on the selected fields and inputs. The issue I have for one field in particular is the table stores NULL Values. The criteria for the query looks like this:

```
 IIf([Checkbox]=-1,[Data in Form],([Field]Like "*" Or [Field]Is Null))
```

If I use this code as criteria for the field in the query, it only works when a value is in the form and the checkbox is selected. If I use the code as an expression, it returns the NULL values when the checkbox is not selected but returns all the records when the checkbox is selected and a value is entered. if I use `Like "*" or Is Null` as a criteria, it works returning all the records so why isn't it working as a part of the IIF statement?

Comment: How is `[Field] Like "*" Or [Field] Is Null` different to `TRUE`?

Comment: Like it was said, your condition is always true (it either has a value, or is null, either way it's true)

Comment: Its sort of like a filter, if the checkbox is 'TRUE' use the data user submits to specify the results returned, if its 'FALSE' return all the values which include NULL values

Comment: @CyberClaw not sure I follow, the condition would be the checkbox which the value can be -1 'TRUE' or 0 'FALSE'

Comment: The point was, the expression [Field]Like "*" Or [Field]Is Null doesn't do anything because it's supposed to return everything (it's always true). There should be an easier way to retrieve all records, like using a * or maybe leaving it empty. Since IIf can be used in so many ways and places, it's hard to understand exactly where it's inputing that expression. Also, checkbox is boolean, so using [Checkbox] = True might be more readable, or simply [Checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

Finding it hard to follow (lots of test data and expected results is always welcome) but I'm thinking something like this:

Standard logic rewrite rule

```
IF A THEN B
```

is equivalent to

```
( NOT A OR B )
```

So your search condition could be something like:

```
WHERE ( checkbox1 = FALSE OR field1 = input1 OR field1 IS NULL )
  AND ( checkbox2 = FALSE OR field2 = input2 OR field2 IS NULL )
  AND ( checkbox3 = FALSE OR field3 = input3 OR field3 IS NULL )
```

---

UPDATE

Something more like:

```
WHERE NameColumn = NameInput
      AND ( SearchEditioncheckbox = FALSE 
            OR EditionColumn = EditionInput 
            OR EditionColumn IS NULL )
```

---

FURTHER UPDATE

Could be:

```
WHERE NameColumn = NameInput
      AND ( SearchEditioncheckbox = FALSE 
            OR EditionColumn = EditionInput )
```

or possibly:

```
WHERE NameColumn = NameInput
      AND ( SearchEditioncheckbox = FALSE 
            OR EditionColumn = EditionInput 
            OR ( EditionColumn IS NULL AND EditionInput IS NULL )
```

Comment: yes this should work in theory but sadly it doesn't. tried it that way as well
Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish
If a user is searching for a book in a library and they can search by Name and Edition. They should be able to search by the Name only leaving the Edition checkbox and field blank which should return all the values including NULLs however if they specify the edition then it should return values based on the Name and Edition only

Comment: What's the purpose of using checkboxes? If you enter a value, all records containing that value will be retrieved. If you don't enter a value, all records will be retrieved (including the ones having NULL values)....

Comment: @Rene while you are correct in the sense that the checkboxes don't provide any additional functionality the principle is the same i.e. "If checkbox is checked" is the same as "If textbox is empty". The issue really is capturing all Values including NULLs or the value entered.

Comment: @onedaywhen the only problem with your solution is it will return NULL values even when an Edition is specified

Comment: @TT CAM, so if the checkboxes don't provide any additional functionality then ditch them. And use `Like "*" or Is Null` as criteria.

Comment: Try my latest suggestions.